# Can't remove flutter_webview_plugin from flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutterwebviewplugin

I am updating the flutter version and so on the gradle version, but since flutter_webview_plugin is deprecated, i keep receiving this error, even after deleting the flutter_webview_plugin dependencies:

> Task :flutter_webview_plugin:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
> C:\Users\Downloads\flutter_windows_3.0.0-stable\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_webview_plugin-0.4.0\android\src\main\java\com\flutter_webview_plugin\WebviewManager.java:395: error: cannot find symbol
> webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(appCacheEnabled);
> ^
> symbol:   method setAppCacheEnabled(boolean)
> location: class WebSettings
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> 1 error

[flutter_webview_plugin search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A01wv.png)

I have already tried to run 'flutter clean' and 'flutter pub get', and restarting vscode.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to delete

`build` directory,

`ios/Podfile`,

`ios/Podfile.lock`,

`pubspec.lock`

And then try running after restarting vscode

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```